# In NetSuite how to add custom Advanced PDF template?

Tags: netsuite

How to I add a custom template, so that it's available for selection here, in the drop down shown:

[image: NetSuite Custom Transaction Form Screenshot]

I guess I need a custom one, not the standard one, so that I'm able to modify it.

**I've perused all the docs** and nothing — no way to find how to add a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to Customization > Forms > Advanced PDF/HTML Templates, find the Standard Expense Report PDF/HTML Template and click Customize at the left of the row where that entry appears. (Note: in that list you will see Customize beside all standard templates, and Edit beside custom templates).

Save the copy of the template and you should see it in the list with Expense Report in the Type column.  Then go back to your Custom Transaction Form (as in your screenshot) and you should see the added custom template available for selection.